# ZAP HUD is different

Tags: zap

Started to get to grips with the OWASP ZAP tool, and can't solve the problem related to the ZAP HUD.

Why does the ZAP HUD frames (on the left- and right-hand sides of page) on some sites (like Github) contain full set of tools, but on other sites (like google) it doesn't?

[image]

[image]

As example, at Google, nothing happens when I click on the green add tool button

Answer (score 2):

In the second case the HUD has failed to load :(
If this happens then try refreshing your browser.

If it happens consistently then feel free to raise an issue, telling us which browser and sites are not working: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud/issues

The HUD is actually injected using a set of particularly nasty techniques and unfortunately they do not always work.